# Change row Background in JTable Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a table in my project called `tasktable`. It retrives data from database (oracle). How can I change the color of the row that has the color in the cell ex. (i,8) automatically when I click the refresh button?

I have tried so many times to put that source code on specific row, but it ended up coloring all the table:

```
          int count;      
          count = tasktable.getRowCount();
         for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
            { 
                  rr = new Object ();
                   rr = tasktable.getModel().getValueAt(i,8);
                   if(rr.equals("GREEN"))
                   {
                 setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                   }
                    if(rr.equals("red"))
                   {
                       setBackground(Color.red);
                   }
                     if(rr.equals("BLUE"))
                   {
                      setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                   }
                      if(rr.equals("yellow"))
                   {
                     setBackground(Color.yellow);
                   }
                       if(rr.equals("pink"))
                   {
                     setBackground(Color.pink);
                   }
                       if(rr.equals(null))
                   {
                     setBackground(null);
                   }
```

how can help me out upon this problem ?

Comment: You really should do some research before asking. This is a pretty common and easy thing to do. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3550006/933756

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the background color of a row in a JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875607/change-the-background-color-of-a-row-in-a-jtable)

Comment: You might want to read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the JTable column and row color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548986/how-do-i-set-the-jtable-column-and-row-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setBackground()` sets the background color of the `JTable`, not the background color of each row or cell.  You need a `TableCellRenderer`, as @Recursed said.

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) to your table.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is changing row color, subclass your `JTable` and override the [`prepareRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) method:

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                             int row,
                             int column) {    
     Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
     if (row == HIGHLIGHT_ROW) {
          c.setBackground(BG_COLOR); 
     }
     return c;
}
```

Comment: i try to write your code but it show to me this error                                   cannot find symbol
  symbol: method prepareRenderer(javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,int,int)

Comment: Hmm...I'd need more info to tell you more about what's wrong.  What's the full error message?  What is the code you're trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                  table,  value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

 String s =  table.getModel().getValueAt(row, VALIDATION_COLUMN ).toString();
 comp.setForeground(Color.red);
```

> http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/541-how-change-color-jtable-row-having-particular-value.html