# Change background color of JTable row based on column value issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848314/change-background-color-of-jtable-row-based-on-column-value) question I did this:

```
public class ShowTicketPlanning extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static String prevTicket="";
    private static int color=1;
    public ShowTicketPlanning() {
        initComponents();

        for (int i = 0; i < C.GameList.size(); i++) {
            gameSelectGameCB.addItem(C.GameList.get(i).printForList());
        }
    }
private void gameSelectGameCBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

        int ind = gameSelectGameCB.getSelectedIndex();
if (C.GameList.size() > 0) {

            DefaultTableModel tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) dbgPlanTBL.getModel();

            while (tmodel.getRowCount() > 0) {
                tmodel.removeRow(0);
            }
String columnNames[] = new String[C.DBGList.get(ind).getDrawDayList().size()];
            int gameDrawSize = C.DBGList.get(ind).getDrawDayList().size();
            for (int z = 0; z < gameDrawSize; z++) {
                columnNames[z] = C.DBGList.get(ind).getDrawDayList().get(z).getDrawNumber() + ":" + C.DBGList.get(ind).getDrawDayList().get(z).getCdc() + ":" + ES.dayToShortDay(C.DBGList.get(ind).getDrawDayList().get(z).getDay());
            }
            String dataValues[][] = {};

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames);
            dbgPlanTBL.setModel(model);
for (int t = 0; t < C.TicketList.size(); t++) {//for all tickets
                for (int b = 0; b < C.TicketList.get(t).getBoardList().size(); b++) {
                    Object[] ob = new Object[gameDrawSize];
                    for (int brpd = 0; brpd < C.TicketList.get(t).getBoardList().get(b).getBoardResultPerDrawList().size(); brpd++) {
                        int d = C.TicketList.get(t).getBoardList().get(b).getBoardResultPerDrawList().get(brpd).getDrawIndex();
                        if (C.DBGList.get(ind).isHasRaffle()) {
                            ob[d] = C.TicketList.get(t).getTicketRefName() + ":" + b
                                    + ":" + C.TicketList.get(t).getBoardList().get(b).getBoardResultPerDrawList().get(brpd).getNumberResult()
                                    + ":" + C.TicketList.get(t).getBoardList().get(b).getBoardResultPerDrawList().get(brpd).getRaffleResult();
                        } else {
                            ob[d] = C.TicketList.get(t).getTicketRefName() + ":" + b
                                    + ":" + C.TicketList.get(t).getBoardList().get(b).getBoardResultPerDrawList().get(brpd).getNumberResult();
                        }
                    }
                    model.addRow(ob);
                }

            }
DefaultTableModel amodel = (DefaultTableModel) dbgPlanTBL.getModel();
            int tableSize = dbgPlanTBL.getRowCount();
            //System.out.println("rows:"+tableSize);
            int tableCol = dbgPlanTBL.getColumnCount();
            //System.out.println("cols:"+tableCol);
            for (int r = 0; r < tableSize; r++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < tableCol; col++) {
                    if (amodel.getValueAt(r, col) == null) {

                    } else {

                        dbgPlanTBL.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ShowTicketPlanning.CustomRenderer());
                        dbgPlanTBL.getCellEditor(r, col).getTableCellEditorComponent(dbgPlanTBL, dbgPlanTBL.getValueAt(r, col), true, r, col).setForeground(Color.red);


                    }
                }
            }

//define column width..............
            TableColumnModel tcm = dbgPlanTBL.getColumnModel();

            for (int i = 0; i < (tcm.getColumnCount()); i++) {
                tcm.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(120);
            }
            dbgPlanTBL.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ShowTicketPlanning.CustomRenderer());
        }

    }
```

```java
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value == null) {
            setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        } else {
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ":");
            String ref = st2.nextElement().toString();
            if (prevTicket.equals(ref)) {
                if (color == 1) {
                    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
                } else {
                    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
                }
            } else {
                if (color == 1) {
                    color = 2;
                } else {
                    color = 1;
                }
                if (color == 1) {
                    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
                } else {
                    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
                }
            }
            prevTicket=ref;
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

So I have tickets that each ticket has more than one board. And I want to change color per ticket.

Result:

[image: So the result is this]

The colors are correct, however after scrolling the colors become irregular as the following image.

[image: incorrect outcome]

Note: Each "ticket0, ticket1, ticket2" etc should have alternating colors.

Comment: `color` variable is not defined here. Please post the code containing the issue.

Comment: I thought it was just the CustomRenderer that was import.I updated the code..thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to check out how this snippet solves this problem and apply it in your own program.

I'll have to disclaim this by saying that I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this, but it works in the sense that it doesn't have the odd behavior that you are describing (row coloring getting messed up when scrolling). I also added some code to account for sorting events and inserting/deleting/updating rows.

My snippet keeps track of colors in an array, so once a color is established for a row it doesn't establish it again. The renderer just gets the color from the color store.

For explanation of what the snippet does, see the comments inside.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableWithAlternatingColorsExample {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        /* The alternating colors */
        public static final Color color1 = new Color(204,204,204);
        public static final Color color2 = new Color(255,255,255);

        /** The model index of the key column, ie the model column from which the key is derived. */
        public static final int modelKeyColId = 0;

        /** The color store that stores the colors for each row in the view. 
         *  Indexed with view index to retrieve color for a row in the view. */
        private ArrayList<Color> colorStore = new ArrayList<>( );

        /** Reset all colors in the color store. */
        public void resetAllColors() {
            colorStore = new ArrayList<>(Math.max(10,colorStore.size()));
        }

        /** Reset all colors in the color store from a certain view index on. */
        public void resetColorsFrom(int row) {
            if(row==0) 
                resetAllColors();
            else {
                ArrayList<Color> retainedColors = new ArrayList<>(Math.max(10,colorStore.size()));
                retainedColors.addAll(colorStore.subList(0,Math.min(row-1,colorStore.size()-1)));  // copy retained colors
                colorStore = retainedColors;
            }
        }

        /** Determines the key value from a cell value. */
        private Object getCellKeyVal(Object cellValue) {
            return new StringTokenizer(cellValue.toString(),":").nextElement();
        }

        /** Retrieves the key value for a certain row. */
        private Object getRowKeyVal(JTable t,int viewRowId) {
            int modelRowId = t.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowId);                 // convert row view index to model index to index the model
            Object cellValue = t.getModel().getValueAt(modelRowId,modelKeyColId); // get cell value from model, because the column might not be present in the view
            return getCellKeyVal(cellValue);
        }

        /** Prepares the color store for a certain row in the view. 
         *  After calling this method colors for the range [0,row] will be present in the color store. 
         *  Call this method to ensure that <i>colorStore.get(row)</i> will return a color. */
        private void prepareColorStore(JTable t,int row) {
            if(colorStore.size()>row) return;                            // color already present for row
            if(colorStore.isEmpty()) colorStore.add(color1);             // if color store empty, start with the first color
            if(row==0) return;
            Object curKeyVal = getRowKeyVal(t,colorStore.size()-1);
            while(colorStore.size()<=row) {                              // add colors until color present for row
                Object prevKeyVal = curKeyVal;
                curKeyVal = getRowKeyVal(t,colorStore.size());
                if(prevKeyVal.equals(curKeyVal))                         // compare key values between current and previous row
                    colorStore.add(colorStore.get(colorStore.size()-1)); // add previous color in store when key values are equal
                else if(colorStore.get(colorStore.size()-1)==color1)     // reference compare because color instances are fixed
                    colorStore.add(color2);                              // add alternating color when key values differ
                else
                    colorStore.add(color1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value,isSelected,hasFocus,row,column);
            if(!table.isRowSelected(row)) {
                prepareColorStore(table,row);         // ensure color is present for row
                c.setBackground(colorStore.get(row)); // set color from color store
            }
            return c;
        }
    };

    private static JTable createTable() {
        Vector<Vector<Object>> rowData = new Vector<>( Arrays.asList( 
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::","ticket0:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::","ticket25:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::","ticket0:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::","ticket1:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::","ticket1:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::","ticket10:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::","ticket10:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::","ticket11:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::","ticket11:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::","ticket12:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::","ticket12:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::","ticket13:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::","ticket13:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::","ticket14:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::","ticket17:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::","ticket14:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::","ticket15:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::","ticket15:1::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::","ticket16:0::"})),
            new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::","ticket16:1::"}))
        ));
        Vector<Object> colData = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"1:103:Wed","2:106:Sat","3:110:Wed","4:110:Sat","5:117:Wed","6:120:Sat","7:124:Wed","8:127:Sat"}));
        final JTable t = new JTable(rowData,colData);

        DefaultTableCellRenderer tcr = new AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer(); 
        Enumeration<TableColumn> e = t.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) 
            e.nextElement().setCellRenderer(tcr); // all table columns share the same AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer instance

        t.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); 
        /* When the row sorter changes, reset all colors in the color store.
         * When row sorting changes, the row view indices will point to different rows in the model, so the color store needs to be reset. */
        t.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {
            @Override
            public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
                ((AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer) t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getCellRenderer()).resetAllColors(); // all rows share the same AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer instance, so pick the renderer from the first column and reset color store
            }
        });

        /* Add a model listener to listen for inserted/deleted/updated rows. When rows are inserted/deleted/updated, the row colors could change for subsequent rows. 
         * Determines the minimum view index for the inserted/deleted/updated rows, then resets the color store from that view index on. */
        t.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int minViewId;
                switch(e.getType()) {
                    case TableModelEvent.INSERT:
                    case TableModelEvent.DELETE:
                        minViewId = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        for(int r=e.getFirstRow();r<=e.getLastRow();++r) { // determine minimum view index for inserted/deleted rows
                            int viewId=t.convertRowIndexToView(r);         // convert model index to view index
                            if(viewId>=0 && viewId<minViewId)              // due to filtering, it is possible that inserted/deleted rows are not visible in the view (convert will return -1 in that case)
                                minViewId=viewId;
                        }
                        if(minViewId!=Integer.MAX_VALUE)                   // if any of the inserted/deleted rows were visible, reset the color store from the minimum view index on  
                            ((AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer) t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getCellRenderer()).resetColorsFrom(minViewId);
                        break;

                    case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                        int r = e.getFirstRow();
                        if(r==TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW)
                            return;                                        // outside scope for this example
                        if(e.getColumn()!=TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS && e.getColumn()!=AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer.modelKeyColId)
                            return;                                        // only listen for updates in the key column
                        minViewId = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        for( ;r<=e.getLastRow();++r) {                     // determine minimum view index for updated rows
                            int viewId=t.convertRowIndexToView(r);         // convert model index to view index
                            if(viewId>=0 && viewId<minViewId)              // due to filtering, it is possible that updated rows are not visible in the view (convert will return -1 in that case)
                                minViewId=viewId;
                        }
                        if(minViewId!=Integer.MAX_VALUE) {                 // if any of the updated rows were visible, reset the color store from the minimum view index on & repaint
                            ((AlternatingColorOnKeyRenderer) t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getCellRenderer()).resetColorsFrom(minViewId);
                            t.repaint();                                   // repaint necessary for UPDATE events to update colors in the view
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return t;
    }

    protected static JButton createAddButton(final JTable t) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Add row randomly");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) t.getModel();
                Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::","ticket77:0::"}));
                int index = new Random().nextInt(t.getRowCount()+1); // random index to insert
                if(index<t.getRowCount())
                    dtm.getDataVector().add(index,newRow);           // use the dataVector from DefaultTableModel to insert
                else
                    dtm.getDataVector().add(newRow);
                dtm.fireTableRowsInserted(index,index);              // notify the view that a row was inserted
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JTable t = createTable();
                f.add(new JScrollPane(t),BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.add(createAddButton(t),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.setSize(500, 500);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @ManosKammas Of course, the snippet was an example that works so you can use the ideas in your own program. I slightly modified it to make it clearer that it uses the value in the first column in the model to determine the "key value".

Comment: Can you please explain to me what these lines of code means?
`for(int r=e.getFirstRow();r<=e.getLastRow();++r) {
      int viewId=t.convertRowIndexToView(r);
      if(viewId>=0 && viewId<minViewId) 
            minViewId=viewId;
}
if( minViewId!=Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      ((CustomRenderer)t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getCellRenderer()).resetColorsFrom(minViewId);`

Comment: @ManosKammas Do you have a specific section you want explained, or a breakdown of all methods in the snippet?

Comment: @ManosKammas The intent of the function is to determine the minimum view index of all rows that were inserted or deleted. Then the color store is deleted from that index on. All `TableColumns` share the same `CustomRenderer` instance (see table creation), so the renderer of the first column is cast to `CustomRenderer`, and the function to clear the color store from `minViewId` on is cleared.

Comment: I created a mirror Array and I defined the row color when I added a row(ticket) in the table.Then I run this.  
 `for (int r = 0; r < tableSize; r++) {  
         for (int col = 0; col < tableCol; col++) {  
               if (amodel.getValueAt(r, col) != null) {  
                 dbgPlanTBL.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ShowTicketPlanning.CustomRenderer());  
                     dbgPlanTBL.getCellEditor(r, col).getTableCellEditorComponent(dbgPlanTBL, dbgPlanTBL.getValueAt(r, col), true, r, col).setBackground(ColorList.get(r).getColor());
   }
 }
 }`

Comment: @ManosKammas Know what, if I have time later today I'll give a breakdown of what every method does. I realize this snippet may be a little too much to understand easily (it's not properly documented). I'll drop a comment when I supplied some explanation.

Comment: Please do.That would be good, because it's the first time I use JTable and tableModel. I know that Netbeans makes things easy to do, but you dont get the knowledge.

Comment: @ManosKammas Updated, explanation as comments in this snippet.