# How to change color of column in JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

My row in the table is marked, but I want to fill with color the selected column too.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548986/how-do-i-set-the-jtable-column-and-row-color) it may help

Comment: A custom cell renderer is the solution you're looking for, perhaps have a look at [Using cell renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: See TableCellRenderer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the JTable column and row color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548986/how-do-i-set-the-jtable-column-and-row-color)